# How to enable authentication while calling Hudson/Jenkins job remotely

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, hudson-plugins

How to enable authentication while calling the Hudson/Jenkins job remotely?

We are currently using Hudson v3.0.1-b2 version.

We call Hudson job remotely to start builds, using Hudson rest api's.

We want to enable authentication while calling Hudson job remotely now. Read online there is a way to generate API Token for the user and use that while calling the Hudson job remotely.

In the Hudson version we are using, we don't see that show API Token user for the user under user config section. please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*Launching a build with parameters:*

Parameters are Case Sensitive!

When passing parameters through the URL, casing is important! For example token=TOKEN&MESSAGE=yo will not work if the job defines the parameter as Message.

A build can be started just by POSTing to
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?PARAMETER=Value
All parameters need to be properly URL-escaped. To use with wget, quote the URL on the command line too.

The parameter delay=0sec can be added to start the build immediately.
To use a Run Parameter, the value should be in the format jobname#buildNumber (eg. "&MyRunParam=foo-job%2399" for foo-job #99)

**If you are using an authorization token to trigger the builds (Job -> Configure -> 'Build Triggers' -> 'Trigger builds remotely (e.g., from scripts)'), you can access:
http://server/job/myjob/buildWithParameters?token=TOKEN&PARAMETER=Value**
(Note that the & will need to be escaped, or the whole URL quoted, if using a Unix shell script.)

---

If you are using Matrix-based security (under "Configure Global Security" >> Authorization), then the "Trigger builds remotely" option will go away because it is presumed that you will be authenticating requests using a Jenkins user account.

In order to do that you can make an HTTP request with the username/password (or even better username/API Token):

curl -X POST "https://username:api-token@JENKINS_URL/job/Example/build"

Get API user and token:

Login to jenkins in http://192.168.99.20:8080 address.
Click your username (mine is admin) on right hand side of the page.
Select "Configure" option which will take you to http://192.168.99.20:8080/user/admin/configure page.
In "API Token" section click "Show API token" button.
Note "User ID" and "API Token" to use in your curl command later on. e.g. admin:85703fb68927f04968630e192e4927cb

---

If all above is not the solution to your problem, you could try the following plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Token+Root+Plugin

Examples:

Trigger the RevolutionTest job with the token TacoTuesday:

`buildByToken/build?job=RevolutionTest&token=TacoTuesday`

Trigger the RevolutionTest job with the token TacoTuesday and parameter Type supplied with the value Mexican:

`buildByToken/buildWithParameters?job=RevolutionTest&token=TacoTuesday&Type=Mexican`